# Different Templates for Woocommerce Parent and Child Sub Categories

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, templates, taxonomy

I need a way to have 2 different layouts for Woocommerce prodcut categories. One for categories that contain products and another for categories that show sub-categories. I've been scouring the internet trying to find the relevant code but can't seem to find anything close to what I need.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can achieve this on my site?

Thanks in advance,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way to use different layout for child and parent terms is to check, if the current queried object has parent or not and then include the right template part based on a if statement. For example like this,

```
// in your taxonomy/term template file
$current_term = get_queried_object();
// parent property is either 0 or the parent ID
if ( $current_term->parent ) {
  get_template_part( 'term-child-template' );
} else {
  get_template_part( 'term-parent-template' );
}
```

I haven't tested the following example, but you could probably use `template_include` filter also to switch templates, if the current object is a child or parent term.

```
function child_or_parent_taxonomy_template( $template ) {
  $current_object = get_queried_object();
  if ( is_a( $current_object, 'WP_Term' ) ) {
    $term_template = $current_tax->parent ? 'child' : 'parent';
    $term_template = locate_template( array( "term-{$term_template}-template.php" ) ); // update as per your setup
    if ( '' !== $term_template ) {
      return $term_template;
    }
  }
  return $template;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'child_or_parent_taxonomy_template', 99 );
```

Comment: That's great thanks, works a treat!